# How do I edit Parental Controls for allowed web sites in macOS?

Tags: macos, parental-controls

We have our family computer (currently running OS X 10.12.6) set up so the kids can only access whitelisted sites.  That is, under System Preferences -> Parental Controls -> Web we have selected "Allow access to only these websites".

Today our younger daughter was trying to access a web site for school, so I needed to whitelist the site.  But then it kept denying access so I have to try to figure out what is going on.

My best guess is that it is not whitelisting by domain, instead it is making us whitelist every single page on the site.  Obviously this is ridiculous.  I went to look at which sites were currently whitelisted, but all it will show me is the title of the page, which is useless.

Even sillier is the fact that it will let me edit the title!  What does this do?  Surely it's not matching off the page's title, as that would break the whitelist if the page title ever changed!

I was hoping to be able to right click or get info or something and see what actual URLs it whitelisted when I authorized the page, but I can't figure out how to get this information.  I'm assuming if I could do that I could put a wildcard or something.

My questions:

- Is there some way to edit the URL of whitelisted pages directly in the settings?
- If not, is there a plist or other config file somewhere I can edit to accomplish this?